# How to Activate - Offiline Salesforce for Enterpise Edition - Using Salesforce in Mobile

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, offline

I found following very interesting document on Salesforce.com

[Salesforce Offline Edition](http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/offline-edition.pdf)

I want to use this Offline feature for one of my Enterprise Edition Client who will be using this on **Mobile.**

I want to know what are the Basic Steps to get it done.

Any suggestions or Directions will be really helpfull !

Answer (score 1):

The [Salesforce Offline Cheatsheet](https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_offline_cheatsheet.pdf) should help you get started. It has details of all the intial steps like installation, logging in, synchronizing data etc.

Additional details could be found under the [help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=offline_def.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: I did followed all the things. Its installing one .exe on my Desktop. But I want this Offline Functionality for Mobile. I am using my whole Salesforce Org on Mobile. How can I achieve the same for Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Connect Offline is a client application that lets you access a subset of Salesforce records using the same browser-based interface as the online system but without an Internet connection. Use Connect Offline to view, edit, create, and delete accounts, activities, contacts, opportunities, leads, and custom object records (including relationship groups). You can also add and update products and schedules on opportunities.

For connect offline see this link...

[enter link description here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=offline_install.htm)